# Java Triangle Calculator

Tags: java, geometry

I have to create a java program where I ask the user for a three letter name of the triangle. Then I ask for three coordinates(Which are the three letters they just typed in). How do I separate the three letters they type in? Here is what my final output should look like. This is the example my professor gave us. Can someone please help me figure this out. I understand how to do the calculations but I don't know how to separate the coordinates from the name the user gives.

```
Enter the three letter name of triangle: jqc
Enter coordinates of vertex J: .1 .1
Enter coordinates of vertex Q: 2.2 .1
Enter coordinates of vertex C: 1.15 .7

--- Side lengths ---
JQ: 2.1
QC: 1.2093386622447826
CJ: 1.2093386622447821
--- Sorted ---
1.2093386622447821, 1.2093386622447828, 2.1

--- Other measures ---
Perimeter = 4.518677324489565
Area = 0.6300000000000003
Center = ( 1.1500000000000001, 0.3 )

--- Triangle types ---
Right triangle: false
Equilateral triangle: false
Isosceles triangle: true
Scalene triangle: false
```

Comment: One way: split a line of input with `String.split(...)` A split that uses a whitespace regex could work: `myString.split("\\s+");` which returns an array of your number Strings which you'll have to parse with `Double.parseDouble(...)`.

Comment: Well I get everything really just not dividing the letters into individual points. I understand everything else except the first part. I already typed up the rest of the code I just forgot about the points in the beginning.

Comment: It's your homework, so when you're at home: Start read your Java book or the Java documentation, then, after you have an idea of how java works start to work (code)!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Answer (score 1):

> How do I separate the three letters they type in?

You can use String.charAt to find the character at a given index.

For instance,

`String example = "string";  // example.charAt(2) would be r`

Then you could join the first two characters (to get the first side name) and do the same for the two remaining sides.

Answer (score 0):

It is another way :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println("Enter the three letter name of triangle:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String threeName = in.nextLine();
    String firstName = threeName.trim().substring(0, 1);
    String secondName = threeName.trim().substring(1, 2);
    String lastName = threeName.trim().substring(2, 3);
    System.out.println(firstName);
    System.out.println(secondName);
    System.out.println(lastName);       
    System.out.println("Enter coordinates of vertex " + firstName.toUpperCase());

    //And continue this code


}
```